# Recovery of scp overwritten file

Tags: ext4, recovery, raid6

I had two 2GB txt files a.txt and b.txt that I wanted to copy to another directory using scp.
However I accidently didn't type the destination directory and typed the following commands

```
scp *.txt
```

and it copied a.txt over b.txt!
my filesystem is ext4 (and it uses raid-6) and the OS is Ubuntu. Is there any way to recover the b.txt file?

Comment: This is why RAID is not a backup

Comment: @gronostaj you are right. I just said for information.